# Mysql select unique field from a groupped table

Tags: mysql

I have table named as posts

```
|id|user_id|title|description|
```

likes table like this

```
|id|user_id|post_id|
```

here is my sql code

```
select count(likes.id) as like_count, posts.* from `posts` left join 
`likes` on `likes`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` where `posts`.`status` = 'A' 
group by `posts`.`id` order by `like_count` desc LIMIT 6
```

Here is the result

```
|like_count |  id | user_id | title | description |
---------------------------------------------------
     17     | 723 |   12    | ...   | ....        |
     15     | 721 |   15    | ...   | ....        |
     14     | 711 |   12    | ...   | ....        |
     13     | 700 |   12    | ...   | ....        |
     12     | 800 |   11    | ...   | ....        |
     12     | 920 |   12    | ...   | ....        |
```

as you see user_id 12 is repeating thee times, I want only one post from one user.

Is there a way to select most liked post of each user, and make user_id don't repeat.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your schema requires further explanation.  The `posts` table relates users to posts, and then `likes` does the same.  What was your intention when you designed the tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the user_id on posts is probably the user that created it, and the user_id on likes table is the user who liked it. I don't think there's anything wacky about that.

Comment: @DavidAllen Feel free to give an answer, but be prepared to iterate a few times (or more).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes DavidAllen is correct user_id on posts is the user that created it, and the user_id on likes table is the user who liked it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this may not be the most efficient solution, but this is the first that came to my mind. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support window functions so the task is way harder and less elegant than the approach one would take using window functions.

Most liked **posts** of each user which will repeat `user_id` if there happens to be more than one post with equal number of likes and that number is the greatest for particular user:

```
select
  user_likes.post_user_id,
  user_likes.like_count,
  p.id as post_id,
  p.title,
  p.description
from (
  select 
    p.user_id         as post_user_id, 
    MAX(l.like_count) as like_count
  from posts p
  inner join (select post_id, count(*) as like_count from likes group by post_id) l on p.id = l.post_id
  group by p.user_id
  ) user_likes
  inner join (select post_id, count(*) as like_count from likes group by post_id) l on user_likes.like_count = l.like_count
  inner join posts p on l.post_id = p.id
```

If you really need one row per user then in case of ties in number of likes for different posts you need to pick a strategy to retrieve only one of those. For example you could take the one that was older by adding grouping on `post_id` and taking the `min()` of its value and joining back to posts table to retrieve it's title and description.

In this case modification of above script would look like:

```
select
  most_liked_post.post_user_id,
  most_liked_post.like_count,
  most_liked_post.post_id,
  p.title,
  p.description
from (
  select
    user_likes.post_user_id,
    user_likes.like_count,
    MIN(l.post_id) AS post_id
  from (
    select 
      p.user_id         as post_user_id, 
      MAX(l.like_count) as like_count
    from posts p
    inner join (select post_id, count(*) as like_count from likes group by post_id) l on p.id = l.post_id
    group by p.user_id
    ) user_likes
    inner join (select post_id, count(*) as like_count from likes group by post_id) l on user_likes.like_count = l.like_count
  group by user_likes.post_user_id, user_likes.like_count
  ) most_liked_post
  inner join posts p on most_liked_post.post_id = p.id
```